# How to add auto-complete for common functions like "Start" and "Update"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Monodevelop can auto-complete code, but it can't auto-complete key functions like `Start`, `Update`, `FixedUpdate`, `OnCollisionEnter` and so on, as such I often misspell the key functions.

Is there a way to add auto-complete or spell-check entries for these common functions?

Comment: I don't think it is possible, because those methods are usually private and MonoDeveloper has no way to guess that you'd like to create those methods.
I am not sure it that would work but you could probably create a class that derives from MonoBehaviour, mark those methods as virtual in that class and always derive from that class instead of MonoBehaviour. But even if it works, i think that the gains are not worth the effort.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov: I thought about that too, but I have a feeling that the Unity runtime/engine might see all those blank virtual methods as something to be executing all the time even though nothing is happening/implemented; it could have an adverse effect on performance.

Comment: @AndreySarafanov  create a class derives from MonoBehaviour maybe the only solution, but it not a elegant solution.  Thank you

Comment: @Chris Sinclair In Android Activity, functions like "onCreate" "onStart" , the Acitivty class have implemented it.  I don't know why MonoBehaviour haven't implement these functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't create autocorrect entries in MonoDevelop, you can create [Code Snippets](http://www.theblacktiestudios.com/theunity/code-snippets-in-monodevelop/) (called Code Templates in MonoDevelop).

A code snippet is a chunk of code that is automatically created when you type an id string (e.g. start) and hit tab. It could be a function, a property, a bit of boilerplate you always find yourself writing (e.g. GetComponent calls). It even shows up in the autocorrect list.

Code snippets are quite powerful, and even allow you to tab over boilerplate and change important things like types and variable names easily and quickly.

Simply create a code snippet (MonoDevelop-> Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> Code Templates-> Add) for each of the items you typically have problems with.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use the [Unity Snippets for MonoDevelop](https://github.com/anchan828/unity-snippets/blob/master/Monodevelop) for your problem. It has got a lot of useful snippets in it, works really great. When the Code Snippet Code appears, **Double Tap TAB key** to insert the template.

[image]

Download the **Unity.template.xml** and create a folder called **Snippets** inside the C:\Users{your_pc_name_here}\AppData\Roaming\MonoDevelop-Unity-5.0 
(or in Windows Press Win+R -> %appdata%) and Copy this file to that folder. On Restarting Monodevelop, the code snippets will be working.

Answer (score 0):

As Andrey said, I believe Unity accesses those methods *by naming/signature convention* and not by any compile-time identity.

What you could do is define an `interface` that represents these methods:

```
public interface IStart
{
    void Start();
}

public interface IUpdate
{
    void Update();
}
```

Then in your script classes, you can inherit from the interfaces you intend to implement:

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour, IStart, IUpdate
{
    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Downside is that these methods become `public`. I've never tried, but I *assume* that Unity would support these methods being implemented via [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx) which might help *hide* those method calls from *typical* API access:

```
public class MyScript : MonoBehaviour, IStart, IUpdate
{
    void IStart.Start()
    {

    }

    void IUpdate.Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Once you have these, if you typo the method signature you will get a compiler error.

As an added bonus, I don't know if MonoDevelop has this option, but in Visual Studio, when you add the interface inheritance in the class declaration, you get a context option to have [Visual Studio automatically implement](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2006/10/a_quick_visual_.html) the interface method signatures (either implicitly or explicitly).

Comment: Thank you!  I have thought about that too.  But it not a sexy solution.

Comment: @Jonguo: Well, I suppose it depends on your definition of sexy. Personally, I'll take compile-time validation and type-safety any day.

Answer (score 0):

this problem take me hours too and didn't fix ant the end.
BUT i found out we can integrate Microsoft visual studio code IDE simply whit Unity since 5.5 version.
need no more plugins and easily set is as default IDE in preferences setting.
then just you need to install unity snippets plugin by searching it as extension and then every thing is done.

Comment: Is it related to the question?

Comment: yes it is. this way helped me to devolved my problem .